# UIImageView frame isn't dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

This is my method to move a player (aka `ball` synchronized with `label`):

```
int x2 = self.ball.frame.origin.x;
int y2 = self.ball.frame.origin.y;
double distance = sqrt(pow((x2 - coords.x), 2.0) + pow((y2 - coords.y), 2.0));

// 140 is just an arbitrary multiplier
NSTimeInterval time = distance / 140;

animating = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:time delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [self.ball setFrame:CGRectMake(coords.x, coords.y, 48, 48)];
    [self.label setFrame:CGRectMake(coords.x - 30, coords.y - 25, 108, 20)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    animating = NO;
}];
```

This code works on one tap, but when a player redirects his move (touches somewhere else while still animating, hence the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`), the distance is wrong. This is because the frame is set to the end point of the first touch, instead of where the animation ended off.

Comment: UIView animation was never intended for a game-play scenario. The whole notion of "redirects his move" is a case in point; you can probably do it with UIView animation, but it's a total hack, because UIView animation is not the live, frame-by-frame world of a genuine animated physics engine. It sounds like you might wish to consider adopting SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get the starting frame position from the object layer.presentationLayer property.
The docs say:

> The layer object returned by this method provides a close
>   approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen.
>   While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and
>   use it to get the current values for those animations.